# Unity3D C# VR: spawning objects at a certain point from the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

So, I've tried this code here and it always spawns an object in front of the player every n-seconds (other function in Update() )

```
  private void SpawnTarget(int prefabIndex = -1)
    {
        GameObject target;
        target = Instantiate(targetPrefabs[0]) as GameObject;
        target.transform.SetParent(transform);
        target.transform.position = Vector3.forward * 3;
        activeTarget.Add(target);
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to randomize the place where it spawns, so that it's not always on the same X and Y coordinates (so it moves around the screen). I've tried the following, which does move the GameObject randomly in X and Y every n-seconds, but it does not follow the player's Z axis anymore, i.e., if the player moves past the target, now it keeps respawning behind the player.

```
  private void SpawnTarget(int prefabIndex = -1)
    {
        GameObject target;
        target = Instantiate(targetPrefabs[0]) as GameObject;
        target.transform.SetParent(transform);
        target.transform.position = target.transform.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), 3.0f);
        activeTarget.Add(target);
    }
```

Alternatively (also same behavior):

```
  private Vector3 newVector;
  private void SpawnTarget(int prefabIndex = -1)
    {
        GameObject target;
        target = Instantiate(targetPrefabs[0]) as GameObject;
        target.transform.SetParent(transform);
        newVector = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), 3.0f);
        target.transform.position = target.transform.position + newVector;
        activeTarget.Add(target);
    }
```

I feel like I'm missing something very basic and very stupid here.

Comment: My idea would be to add 0 for z instead of 3 because you say Vector3 + Vector3 which will add the z axis and not set it to 3 or is this intended?

Comment: Try `target.transform.SetParent(transform, false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is to spawn the prefab at a set position *from the player*. But you're spawning it in world coordinates.

One solution is to parent the prefabs to the parent when you spawn them, and set their *local position*, not world position to the desired spot.

But parenting things to the player is bad news, especially in VR. Trust me.

A better solution would be to store a Vector3 that is the relative location from the player, and then set the prefab's position to that every frame. Something like this.

public class SpawnedPrefab : MonoBehaviour {

```
// this is the position in the player's local space. 
// In your example, random x and y, and z =3
Vector3 positionRelativeToPlayer; 

Transform player;

void Update() {
    this.transform.position = player.TransformPoint(positionRelativeToPlayer);
}
```

}

TransformFrom point takes a point in local space and figures out what it would be in world space.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out the issue.